# Selenium in Docker container does not seem to render Angular 2 app correctly

Tags: angular, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to dockerize an instance of Robot Framework with Selenium 2 and Chrome for automated testing in a continuous integration/deployment environment. I have managed to put together a Dockerfile that creates an image containing the necessary building blocks. I can successfully execute simple RF tests, like one that submits a search on Google.

However, when I try to execute a similarly simple test case targeting our Angular 2 application under test, the test fails. The test consists of three steps: Navigate to login page, fill in login form and submit, wait until the word "Dashboard" appears on the page (timeout 15s, the app loads a lot faster than that). I believe there is some serious rendering or processing issue going on in Selenium, based on the screenshot that I extracted from RF's test execution log.

[image: Screenshot from failed test case in Robot Framework execution log]

Not only is no text displayed whatsoever (only pixelated rectangles), the layout is also very off (parts of the menu buttons moved "one row" down).

Just in case it matters, this is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    udev \
    chromium \
    chromium-chromedriver \
    xvfb \
    bash

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir \
  robotframework==3.0.2 \
  robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0 \
  selenium==3.3.1

# Chrome requires docker to have cap_add: SYS_ADMIN if sandbox is on.
# Disabling sandbox and gpu as default.
RUN sed -i "s/self._arguments\ =\ \[\]/self._arguments\ =\ \['--no-sandbox',\ '--disable-gpu'\]/" /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/options.py

COPY entry_point.sh /opt/bin/entry_point.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/bin/entry_point.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/bin/entry_point.sh" ]
```

And (parts of) entry_point.sh:

```
GEOMETRY="${SCREEN_WIDTH}x${SCREEN_HEIGHT}x${SCREEN_DEPTH}"
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 $GEOMETRY &
export DISPLAY=:99
pybot --outputdir /out /tests
```

I have seen some posts that there are issues with Selenium and Angular 2, and that accessing page elements and finding out when a page has fully loaded is problematic. However, none of those that I have seen seem to apply here. The failing test statement is this:

```
Wait Until Page Contains    dashboard    15s
```

I would expect that as long as Selenium correctly renders the page, the word dashboard (a menu item) will be found within 15s. In a real browser the page under test loads within 2-3s max. Judging by the messed up and incomplete UI layout, the problems seem to lie elsewhere.

Unfortunately, I am dealing with three technologies here that are still fairly new to me, Docker (or Linux in general), Robot Framework and Selenium. It is not clear to me whether this is a problem with Selenium alone, a problem due to Selenium running headless with Xvfd, or something else entirely different.

I appreciate any pointer in which direction I should continue troubleshooting.

Comment: Don't know the problem (looks like something with webfont-loading from the screenshots), but you might be interested in this: https://hackernoon.com/running-karma-tests-with-headless-chrome-inside-docker-ae4aceb06ed3 There is no need for xvfb anymore, you can run headless chrome natively inside docker and we managed to do it according to this tutorial as well. the only thing that didn't work for us was the is-docker checker plugin, so instead we passed an argument from gitlab-ci to the e2e-script, which then selected the fitting environment

Comment: It looks like you don't have any X11 fonts installed on your container. I doubt the problem has anything at all to do with selenium since selenium doesn't render anything, it just connects to other programs. You will probably see this same problem if you simply start up chrome without selenium and without robot.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, now that you mention it, that makes sense. Just strange that amongst all the RF in Docker examples I don't recall seeing font installations.

Comment: @Phil, thanks for that link. I will check it out.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: Your observation about the missing fonts was correct. If you'd like, add an answer to my question and I'll mark it as such.